# Behave (BDD for Python) supports Examples tagging

Tags: python, cucumber, bdd

I am looking to apply tags that works for scenarios & features to examples in following way. It seems to work for cucumber but not for Behave- a BDD framework for Python:

```
Scenario Outline: Something useful
 Given I have <a> 
 When I add <b>
 Then I should have <c>

 Examples: Implemented things 
  | a | b | c | 
  | 0 | 0 | 0 |

 @pending 
 Examples: Not yet implemented things 
  | a | b | c | 
  | 1 | 2 | 3 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure you have Behave 1.2.5

```
pip show behave
```

If it is not Behave 1.2.5, then install the latest version.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/behave/behave
```

Secondly, you may need to apply quote marks around your place holders. For Example.

```
Given I have "<a>"
When I add "<b>"
Then I should have "<c>"
```

Comment: I have behave 1.2.5 , it given following error to be specific:   Parser failure in state next_scenario, at line 8: 'Examples:'